# Set base environment properties of ContextSource

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I need to set [some base properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/AbstractContextSource.java#L571) (like disable SSL checks with custom socket factory) of [ContextSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/AbstractContextSource.java) through [GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.java). Is my option is to use [LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.contextSource(BaseLdapPathContextSource)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java#L200)?

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource()
            .url("ldaps://xxx:636")
            .managerDn("uid=emt,ou=funcids,ou=applications,o=xxx,c=us")
            .managerPassword("XA1zWgAU")
            .and()
            .userSearchBase("o=xxx,c=us")
            .userSearchFilter("(&(uid={0})(objectclass=person))")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=internal,o=xxx,c=us")
            .groupSearchFilter("(&(uid={0})(objectclass=person)(ismemberof=*))");
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```